# 12 months average for group in pandas dataframe based on delivered date condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 250409 entries, 0 to 350928
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------               --------------   -----         
 0   Location             250409 non-null  object        
 1   Code                 250409 non-null  object        
 2   PO                   250409 non-null  float64       
 3   Delivered_Date       250409 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 4   Supplier_Number      250409 non-null  object        
 5   Supplier_Name        250409 non-null  object        
 6   Created_Date         250409 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 7   Original_Quantity    250409 non-null  float64       
 8   Delivered_Quantity   250409 non-null  float64       
 9   Article_description  250409 non-null  object        
 10  Brand                250409 non-null  object        
 11  Category             250409 non-null  object        
 12  Sub_Category         250409 non-null  object        
 13  actual_lead_time     250409 non-null  int64         
 14  OrderedDateMonth     250409 non-null  int64         
 15  OrderedateYear       250409 non-null  int64         
 16  PoDeliveredSequence  250409 non-null  int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(3), int64(4), object(8)
memory usage: 34.4+ MB
```

I'd like three new columns, that calculate last 12 months average actual_lead_time. for the following groupings:

```
Supplier_Number, Brand
Supplier_Number, Sub_Category
Supplier_Number, Category
```

The catch is, it has to be based on the rows within the grouping's where delivereddate date is within 12 months prior to the created_date.

So say in a row Supplier_number = 101010 and Brand = Coca_cola and Created_date 2024-02-12 I'd like to know the average lead time for rows between 2023-02-12 and 2024-02-11 for 101010 Coca_Cola.

So far tried various solutions latest is the following which doesn't seem to really do anything but lock my Python kernel indefinitely:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming hpo_df is your DataFrame with columns Created_Date, Delivered_Date, actual_lead_time, Supplier_Number, Brand, Category, Sub_Category

# Convert Created_Date and Delivered_Date to datetime objects if they are not already
hpo_df['Created_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(hpo_df['Created_Date'])
hpo_df['Delivered_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(hpo_df['Delivered_Date'])

# Function to calculate mean actual_lead_time for last 12 months prior to a given created_date
def mean_lead_time_last_12_months(created_date, supplier_number, additional_col, df):
    # Filter rows based on Supplier_Number and additional_col
    filtered_df = df[(df['Supplier_Number'] == supplier_number) & (df[col] == additional_col)]
    
    # Filter rows where Delivered_Date falls within last 12 months prior to created_date
    filtered_df = filtered_df[(filtered_df['Delivered_Date'] >= created_date -      pd.DateOffset(months=12)) & (filtered_df['Delivered_Date'] < created_date)]
    
    # Calculate mean of actual_lead_time for the filtered rows
    mean_lead_time = filtered_df['actual_lead_time'].mean()
    
    return mean_lead_time

# Iterate over rows and calculate mean actual_lead_time for each row and each additional column
mean_lead_times = []
cols = ['Brand', 'Category', 'Sub_Category']

for index, row in hpo_df.iterrows():
    created_date = row['Created_Date']
    supplier_number = row['Supplier_Number']
    for col in cols:
        additional_col = row[col]
        mean_lead_time = mean_lead_time_last_12_months(created_date, supplier_number, additional_col, hpo_df)
        mean_lead_times.append(mean_lead_time)

    # Add mean_lead_times as a new column in the DataFrame
    hpo_df['mean_lead_time_last_12_months'] = mean_lead_times
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Elerium115 Remember to be plesant with newcomers to the community. The question in this can could have been: ```is there a more efficient way to do this?```.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using `iterrow()` implicitly in your code and when dataframes are of the size you mention, this is rarely a good idea. Using `grouby` and `transform` is a much more suitable way to do things here.

I created this dataframe that mimic the `hpo_df` attributes you provided (good thinking there, otherwise it would have been hard to test. I work in the retail industry, so I have a bunch of these methods already at hand ;-) ).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def random_float(min_val, max_val):
    return min_val + (max_val - min_val) * np.random.random()

n_samples = 200
locations = np.random.choice(['Location1', 'Location2', 'Location3'], n_samples)
codes = np.random.choice(['Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3'], n_samples)
pos = np.random.uniform(1000, 5000, n_samples).round(2)
category = np.random.choice(['Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3'], n_samples)
sub_category = np.random.choice(['SubCategory1', 'SubCategory2', 'SubCategory3'], n_samples)
brand = np.random.uniform(1, 30, n_samples).round(0)
actual_lead_time = np.random.uniform(1, 150, n_samples).round(0)
supplier_names = np.random.choice(['Supplier1', 'Supplier2', 'Supplier3'], n_samples)
article_descriptions = np.random.choice(['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'], n_samples)
original_quantities = np.random.uniform(10, 100, n_samples).round(2)
delivered_quantities = np.random.uniform(1, 90, n_samples).round(2)
ordered_date_months = np.random.randint(1, 13, n_samples)
ordered_date_years = np.random.randint(2018, 2023, n_samples)
po_delivered_sequences = np.random.randint(1, 100, n_samples)

data = {
    'Location': locations,
    'Code': codes,
    'PO': po_delivered_sequences,
    'Supplier': supplier_names,
    'Brand': brand,
    'Supplier_Number': np.random.randint(1000, 9999, n_samples),
    'Item': article_descriptions,
    'Original_Quantity': original_quantities,
    'Delivered_Quantity': delivered_quantities,
    'Ordered_Date_Month': ordered_date_months,
    'Ordered_Date_Year': ordered_date_years,
    'actual_lead_time': actual_lead_time,
    'Category': category,
    'Sub_Category': sub_category
}

hpo_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

delivered_dates = pd.to_datetime(hpo_df['Ordered_Date_Year'].astype(str) + '-' + hpo_df['Ordered_Date_Month'].astype(str) + '-' + (np.random.randint(1, 28, n_samples)).astype(str))
created_dates = pd.to_datetime(hpo_df['Ordered_Date_Year'].astype(str) + '-' + hpo_df['Ordered_Date_Month'].astype(str) + '-' + (np.random.randint(1, 28, n_samples)).astype(str))

hpo_df['Delivered_Date'] = delivered_dates
hpo_df['Created_Date'] = created_dates
```

Now, using exactly the same principle as you, but avoiding `iterow()` I came up with the fooloing method:

```
def mean_lead_time_last_12_months(group, current_created_date):
    recent_deliveries = group[(group['Delivered_Date'] >= current_created_date - pd.DateOffset(years=1)) & (group['Delivered_Date'] < current_created_date)]
    return recent_deliveries['actual_lead_time'].mean()

for grouping in [('Supplier_Number', 'Brand'), ('Supplier_Number', 'Sub_Category'), ('Supplier_Number', 'Category')]:
    hpo_df[f'average_lead_time_12_months_{"_".join(grouping)}'] = hpo_df.groupby(list(grouping) + ['Created_Date'])['actual_lead_time'].transform(lambda x: mean_lead_time_last_12_months(hpo_df.loc[x.index], x.name[2]))


print(hpo_df.head())
```

which returns

```
    Location   Code  PO   Supplier  Brand  Supplier_Number   Item  \
0  Location2  Code2  80  Supplier1   13.0             6136  Item1   
1  Location2  Code1  92  Supplier1   22.0             7256  Item2   
2  Location1  Code2  30  Supplier2    7.0             7364  Item3   
3  Location2  Code3  37  Supplier3   24.0             4520  Item3   
4  Location2  Code1  26  Supplier2   25.0             9001  Item1   

   Original_Quantity  Delivered_Quantity  Ordered_Date_Month  \
0              24.73               87.51                   4   
1              26.00               38.02                   1   
2              75.64               16.64                   5   
3              71.82               30.80                  10   
4              92.10               36.19                  10   

   Ordered_Date_Year  actual_lead_time   Category  Sub_Category  \
...............
1                                                NaN     
2                                               47.0     
3                                               62.0     
4                                               83.0
```

This took `0.8s` (with creating the dataframe. I would suspect it goes quite fast with your actual data.

Comment: Thanks Serge, 

The code works, but only when creating the dataframe like you've done. 
If i run it on my own, it doesn't fail it run successfully but only returns NaN Values. 

Can i debug the code somehow to figure out why?

Comment: Wait Serge, 
I just noticed the code and the dataframe you've made. It returns the actual_lead_time from the same row. And only because in your examples, on a row the Delivered_Date is in the past of the Created_Date which isn't possible. An OrderLine which a row in reality is, will naturally always have a date later than the Created_Date.

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to do the trick, it is however super slow given the length of my dataframe is there are more efficient way to do it?

```
means = []

# Iterate over each row in test_df
for index, row in hpo_df.iterrows():
    # Filter original_df based on the conditions
    filtered_df = hpo_df[
        (hpo_df['Location'] == row['Location']) &
        (hpo_df['Supplier_Number'] == row['Supplier_Number']) &
        (hpo_df['Brand'] == row['Brand']) &
        (filtered_df['Delivered_Date'] >= row['Created_Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=12)) &
        (filtered_df['Delivered_Date'] < row['Created_Date'])]
    
    # Count the number of rows in the filtered dataframe and append to the counts list
    means.append(np.mean(filtered_df['actual_lead_time']))

# Add a new column 'Count' to test_df with the counts
hpo_df['mean'] = means
```